# Upload local file with fetch / content-type: octet-stream

Tags: javascript, fs, fetch-api, azure-cognitive-services, sketchapp

I am currently developing a Sketch Plugin, where an image gets sent to the Microsoft Custom Vision API for object detection.

The Sketch Plugin itself is written in Javascript, a fs polyfill and a fetch polyfill is available. An API call with an image url works perfectly fine. However, I have trouble sending a local file from my computer as I am not 100% how I can access it.

```
    var templateUrl = require('../assets/test.png').replace('file://', '');
    var file = fs.readFileSync(templateUrl);

    var request = postData('https://southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/customvision/v2.0/Prediction/XXXXXXX/image');
    request.then(data => data.json()).then(data => myFunction(data));

    // post request with file
    function postData(url, data) {
    return fetch(url, {  
        method: 'POST',  
        headers: {  
          'Prediction-Key': 'XXXXXXXXXX',
          'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        },  
        body: file,
    })
}
```

Does anyone have experience with sending local files to the image recognition API? Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Best, C

Comment: If it's run in the browser, you can't. I see `fs`, so I presume you're using NodeJS? (I recommend tagging it appropriately)

Comment: Hi @IvanRubinson, thanks for your reply! 
So fetch cannot take local files if its run in the browser? Would a form upload help?
Unfortunately I can't use NodeJS, it's just a polyfill for the script language that plugins for Sketch use (https://github.com/skpm/fs). Sketch plugin uses a Javascript API but could also take Cocoascript code, so if Objective C would help me here, that would also work.

Comment: Okay, maybe you can do it if you ask your user to pick which file they want to upload. Just use a `<input type="file">` kind of tag.